# Java: identify if two regex patterns overlap

Tags: java, regex

Is there a java library or a way to find out if, two given regular expressions like

- `A*`
- `AB*`

will be overlapping = true/false ?

Comment: Sorry can you clarify more, can you show us some expected results?

Comment: @YCF_L both `A*` and `AB*` can match `A`, so their domain (the set of string they will match) overlap. I think the accepted answer of the question Wiktor linked to pretty much covers it and the question could be closed as its duplicate anyway.